# onupgradeneeded event not firing in iOS 10/11 safari web app

Tags: javascript, ios10, ios11, indexeddb

I am working on web app using the indexedDB. Now I am having a weird behaviour in it. At first time when I load my web app(with no tables created), the the onupgradeneeded event will be fired as expected. But if I relaunch my app, and if I want to recreate the tables, then the onupgradeneeded event won't get fired.

```
var version = db.version; //db variable has value on opening db
var request1 = indexedDB.open('ABCD', ++version);
alert('upgrade reqd.')
request1.onupgradeneeded = function(e) {       
    db = e.target.result;
    alert('upgrade event fired')
}
```

I tested in chrome and works fine. But in safari iPad 10/11, it got stuck after the first alert.

Comment: Are you passing in a higher version number?

Comment: I used db.close(), to close the existing db connection before executing the above code. And I found that the issue is due to the proper disconnection. I tried defining db.onClose, but still no result. Please help me out.

Comment: Josh, yes, you can see that in the code. And actually, it works fine in my chrome, even though there is some delay to enter into the upgrade event. The issue is with the iPad safari web app. And my application should work in it.

Comment: 1) What is the variable type of the variable `version`? 2) Do not use window.alert, use console.log please. You are working with an async library and using a sync alert method, it would be better to use a non-blocking method like console.log.

Comment: Its type is integer. I have to remind you again. It's working fine in chrome. But my live application is in iPad safari. That's why i used the alert. Actually, while debugging, I found that the root cause may be due to the unfinished transactions. But I checked using the transaction.oncomplete event, and found that all transactions which I opened, was completed. I am really confused. What's could be with the iPad.